# Could not find plugin "proposal-class-static-block"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, babeljs

I think I might have ran into a glitch. Last night I ran into an error that said "Could not find plugin "proposal-class-static-block". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it." Everytime I add or delete code in my react website it will run this error, what do i do??? I tried npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-static-block but that didnt do anything at all. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Adding my fix in the event someone experiences this error.

Other people have fixed it by running an `npm install` and/or deleting the package-lock.json **lock** file and then running `npm install`.

Those didn't work for me so I figured out the module files causing this error are related to a conflict with older versions of babel/core and babel/preset-env. The versions that fixed my issue were:

"@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",

I added the updated versions to my package.json and running `npm install`. I'm assuming this fix will work with Yarn also. If you keep getting errors when updating your modules, try running `npm install --force`. However, please readup on what this does if you are unfamiliar.

Comment: this worked for me. i was updating from webpack 4 to 5, babel-loader 8 to 9, and then finally unbroke the build by going from babel core and babel preset-env 7.8 to 7.20

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `package-lock.json`, the `node_modules` folder and then adding the plugin with `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-static-block` and in my babel configuration did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

You should try this out

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-static-block
```

before

```
npm install --force
```

node-modules could be deleted which makes clear installation